# How to use dictionaries passed via res.render in node.js (Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have the next code in a handler (router):

```
res.render('./game/home', {username:req.session.name, resources:player.getResources(req.session.name)});
```

The method `getResources()` returns a dictionary like:

```
{wood: 500, stone: 500, iron:300}
```

All variables are ok, but I've tried 100 ways to use it in a jade template and it doesn't work.

That's how I'm using the variable:

```
Hi, #{username}. You have #{resources.wood} wood.
```

`username` is ok, but it throws the next error:

```
"Cannot read property 'wood' of undefined"
```

And secondly, how can I assign the value of "resources" (from res.render) to a local jade variable?

Comment: What is the value of `username`? Did you call `getResource` with the same value when you got the dictionary and when you got `undefined` (note that it is case sensitive)?

Comment: your getResources call actually 'returns' something synchronously and doesn't look it up in a database or anything async?

Comment: Looks like `player.getResources(req.session.name)` is failing, so you should probably post that function as well, and console.log `session.name` etc. to check the values.

Answer (score 0):

This was a big issue for me too.

I used something like this:

```
return res.render(path)
```